# Pyspark udf for populating a column based on two other columns

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following issue since I am a bit of a noob in pyspark. Based on conditions on values coming from two columns I want to populate a third column. The conditions are:

- if semicolon contained in col2, check col1

  - if col1 == 1, take the value before the semicolon
  - if col1 == 2, take the value after the semicolon
- if no semicolon in col1, take the value from col2 as-is

This is what the dataframe looks like.

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24.9;34.9 | 24.9 |
| 2 | 24.9;34.9 | 34.9 |
| 1 | 80.8;90.9 | 80.8 |
| 2 | 80.8;90.9 | 90.9 |
| 1 | 777 | 777 |

I made the following udf which gives the error *Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.*

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def split_by_semicolon_if_exists(col1,col2):
    if (col1.contains(';') == True):
        if col2 == 1:
          result = F.substring(col1, 0, (F.length(col1) - F.expr('locate('';'', col1) - 1')))
        if col2 == 2:
          result = F.substring(col1, F.expr('locate('';'', col1) - 1'), (F.length(col1) - F.expr('locate('';'', col1) - 1')))     
        return result
    else:
      return col1

df = df.withColumn('col3', 
                     split_by_semicolon_if_exists(df['col1'], 
                                                  df['col2']))
```

I have built this udf by googling for the various functions so there probably are multiple issues with it. Can you please help me build a udf for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html) function.

Using UDF:

```py
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [
    {"col1": 1, "col2": "24.9;34.9"},
    {"col1": 2, "col2": "24.9;34.9"},
    {"col1": 1, "col2": "80.8;90.9"},
    {"col1": 1, "col2": "777"},
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)


def get_value(item, value):
    if ";" in value:
        return value.split(";")[item - 1]
    return value


df = df.withColumn("col3", F.udf(get_value, StringType())(F.col("col1"), F.col("col2")))
```

Without UDF:

```
df = df.withColumn(
    "col3",
    F.when(
        F.col("col2").contains(";"), F.split("col2", ";").getItem(F.col("col1") - 1)
    ).otherwise(F.col("col2")),
)
```

Result:

```
root
 |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)

+----+---------+----+                                                           
|col1|col2     |col3|
+----+---------+----+
|1   |24.9;34.9|24.9|
|2   |24.9;34.9|34.9|
|1   |80.8;90.9|80.8|
|1   |777      |777 |
+----+---------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks! Without the udf it works plug-and-play. With your udf, however, I get  'TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable', While I understand the error, I don't understand why my original dataset causes it.

Comment: @chris_to You're welcome! Interesting, could you please provide more information about your original dataset? You can see the types that I used in the example, something is different in your dataset..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

df =spark.createDataFrame(
        data = [(1, "24.9;34.9"),
                (2,"24.9;34.9"),
                (1,"80.8;90.9"),
                (2,"80.8;90.9"),
                (1,"777")],
        schema=["col1","col2"])
df.show()
def split_by_semicolon_if_exists(col1,col2):
    if  ';' in col2 :
        if col1 == 1:
            result = col2.split(';')[0]
        if col1 == 2:
            result = col2.split(';')[1]
        return result
    else:
        return col2

split_by_semicolon_if_exists_udf  =F.udf(split_by_semicolon_if_exists , T.StringType())
    
df = df.withColumn('col3', split_by_semicolon_if_exists_udf(df['col1'], df['col2']))
df.show()
```

To use functions over a column of your dataframe you have to declare them as udf funcions with F.udf(function, return argument type)

You can check this documentation https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-udf-user-defined-function/

Also, python has easier functions to manage strings such as

```
if 'string' in stringVariable :
```

(True/ False if substring is present in main string)

You can also  divide strings in a certain character using

```
string.split(';')
```

(Returns an array of the sepparated parts)

Comment: You are searching for `;` and then splitting the string by `;`. This is not necessary. You can just split: `col2_split = col2.split(';')` `if len(col2_split) <= 1: return col2` `return col2_split[col1 - 1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expr` without having to use a udf here. Since Python indexing starts from 0, you need to subtract 1 from your col1:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("Result",F.expr("""split(col2,';')[int(col1)-1]""")).show()
```

---

```
+----+---------+-----+------+
|col1|     col2| col3|Result|
+----+---------+-----+------+
|   1|24.9;34.9| 24.9|  24.9|
|   2|24.9;34.9| 34.9|  34.9|
|   1|80.8;90.9| 80.8|  80.8|
|   2|80.8;90.9| 90.9|  90.9|
|   1|      777|777.0|   777|
+----+---------+-----+------+
```

The new column `Result` is same as your output in `col3`